# div slides up and stays in position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with a header, a footer and a body, and i have a social media list in it what i want is when i open this page or reload it to make this social media list slide from the bottom and stay fixed in it's place, i tried something but it didn't work here is my code:

```js
$(function(){
    
    $(".mydiv").addClass("active");
    console.log($(".mydiv"));
    
});
```

```css
header{
background-color: red;
height: 100px
}

footer{
background-color: red;
height: 100px
}

div{
transition-property: margin-top;
transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-property: margin-top; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s; 
  margin-top:1000px;
}

div.active
{
margin-top:0px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<body>
<p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>

<div class="mydiv">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Social link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Where do you actually want the list to be displayed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below Example :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suenvudt/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(this).scroll(function(){
  $('.mydiv').css({  
   position:'fixed',
    bottom:'0',
    height:'auto',
    animation:'top 0.5s'
  });
 if($(this).scrollTop() > '360'){
      $('.mydiv').css({
        position:'relative'
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
header{
background-color: red;
height: 100px
}

@keyframes top{
  from{bottom:-30px;}
  to{bottom:0px;}
}
footer{
background-color: red;
height: 100px
}

div{
transition-property: margin-top;
transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-property: margin-top; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s; 
}

div.active
{
margin-top:0px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<body>
<p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content </p>

<div class="mydiv">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Social link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Social link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Your Welcome @jessica.

Comment: when i reach the footer how can i place this div under it? then when i scroll up again it repeats the animation?

Comment: See the Updated snippet above.